# Android Studio: Kotlin dist downloading failed

Tags: android-studio

Starting Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 following notification appears:

> Failed to download Kotlin Compiler Maven artifact (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-dist-for-jps-meta:1.8.20-release). The search was performed in the following repos: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/ You can use Kotlin compiler which is bundled into your IDE. Select 'Bundled' version in 'File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Kotlin Compiler | Kotlin Compiler version'

In settings the Kotlin compiler version is 1.8.20-release. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 11):

You update android studio and then you get the error "Kotlin distribution download failed".

[image]

For this, "*kotlin compiler version*" must be set.

Settings-> Kotlin Compiler -> Kotlin Compiler Version

My "kotlin compiler version" was **1.8.20**. I set "Kotlin compiler version" to **1.8.22**

[image]

I hope it is useful

Answer (score 4):

I fixed on my Mac below setups

1. Open Android Studio -> Settings
2. Click Kotlin Compiler
3. Select 'Bundled' Kotlin Compiler version on dropdown.

it will automatically install or re-open android studio.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by following the instructions in the notification, except that "Kotlin Compiler" is in a top level settings menu in my version of Android Studio (2022.3.1 Patch 1), so I just went there and changed the "Kotlin compiler version" selection to be the bundled version.

Answer (score 0):

Several existing answers effectively say to follow the instructions from the error message itself. That's a very reasonable strategy, but I found the most convenient solution was to delete the offending config file, which is `.idea/kotlinc.xml`.

Or more precisely, because I like to know exactly what I've done and be able to undo it, I renamed the file away:

```
$ mv .idea/kotlinc.xml{,.old}
```

That solved the problem.

---

Here's what was in that file:

```
$ cat .idea/kotlinc.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="KotlinJpsPluginSettings">
    <option name="version" value="1.8.0-release" />
  </component>
</project>
```

I don't believe I ever chose that value — I think it was automatically put there by Android Studio at some point. So the fact that it's wrong is basically Android Studio's fault in the first place, and the fact that it's now giving a cryptic error over it is a bug in Android Studio (or really in IntelliJ, which Android Studio is based on).

I found the investigation in this thread very helpful for understanding what the problem was:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126248